# How does Cygwin specify the seconds of "date"

Tags: git, date, time, github, cygwin

I want to be able to specify a time value in the past, down to the second.  I'll be using this with github.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

The `date` command takes a `-d` or `--date=...` option that lets you specify a date.  The format of the specified date is fairly flexible.  There are also options to control the output format.  For example:

```
$ date -d 'Oct 1 01:23:45'
Sat Oct  1 01:23:45 PDT 2011
$ date -d 'Oct 1 01:23:45' +'%F %T'
2011-10-01 01:23:45
```

`date --help` or `info date` for more details.

You say you'll "be using this with github".  *How* will you be using it with github?  Do you want to pass a formatted date string to some git command?  Details, please.

Comment: I want to sync to an older commit, x number of months ago, without regard for the current time.  I'd like to be able to go back x months, from the 1st second of the month.  Without specifying the seconds value I end up going back x months from the current time (i.e. 1:37 pm and __seconds) and that's not what I want.  Here's my code:  `git checkout $(git rev-list --before "$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -$i months" +%Y-%m)-01" -n 1 HEAD)`

Comment: So you want to do a checkout by date?  Does [this](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/645) help?

Comment: Thanks Keith, I think I got it